# How to convert this two steps command in a single one using zsh/bash script?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want a zsh/bash script to automate the following 2 steps command.

```
$ tar -cf omniauth.wiki.tar omniauth.wiki
$ gzip omniauth.wiki.tar
```

I want something like:

```
$ targzip omniauth.wiki (i.e. targizp <folder-name>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the z option to compress using gzip.

```
tar -czf omniauth.wiki.tar.gz omniauth.wiki
```

Comment: If you use zip with tar you usually call the file .tar.gz, like omniauth.wiki.tar.gz

Comment: Yeah I noticed I forgot to add that when I copied it so I edited it on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can :

```
tar -c omniauth.wiki | gzip > omniauth.wiki.tar.gz
```

As an example of more generic pipe/redirection mechanism. Of course, `tar -czf` makes more sense for this particular case, but in general case not every shell command supports built-in compression, and then you'll have to use pipes....